# Data extraction using imacros search

Tags: imacros

line:

```
{"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.03437400"}
```

code:
`SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"\"ETHBTC\",\"price\":\"(.[^\"]*)\"" EXTRACT="$1"` - extract value "0.03437400", works fine.

but how do i extract here 0.00014137 or  0.00015999 
from this code

```
[{"cur":"BNT","symbol":"BNT/BTC","last":0.00015222,"high":0.00015714,"low":0.00014651,,"best_bid":0.00014137,"best_ask":0.00015999}
```

This value is always different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"\[\{\"cur\":\"BNT\",\"symbol\":\"BNT/BTC\".+\"best_bid\":([\d\.]+)" EXTRACT="$1"
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"\[\{\"cur\":\"BNT\",\"symbol\":\"BNT/BTC\".+\"best_ask\":([\d\.]+)" EXTRACT="$1"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```